# R interaction with some categories

Tags: r, formula

I have a categorical variable and a dummy variable.

```
categorical <- sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE)
dummy <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=TRUE)
y <- rnorm(10)
Data <- data.frame(cbind(y, dummy, categorical))
Data$categorical <- factor(Data$categorical, labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
            y dummy categorical
1   1.2489535     1           A
2   1.0294912     1           C
3  -0.6506571     1           D
4   1.7365180     0           B
5  -1.6664038     1           B
6  -0.3499880     1           A
7   1.1315883     0           B
8  -0.8568375     0           D
9  -0.5332537     0           C
10 -1.8431102     0           B
11  1.2489535     1           B
12  1.0294912     1           A
13 -0.6506571     1           D
14  1.7365180     0           D
15 -1.6664038     1           A
16 -0.3499880     1           A
17  1.1315883     0           B
18 -0.8568375     0           D
19 -0.5332537     0           A
20 -1.8431102     0           D
```

It is very easy to create an interaction variable between these two,

```
model.matrix(y ~ categorical:dummy, data = Data)
   (Intercept) categoricalA:dummy categoricalB:dummy categoricalC:dummy categoricalD:dummy
1            1                  1                  0                  0                  0
2            1                  0                  0                  1                  0
3            1                  0                  0                  0                  1
4            1                  0                  0                  0                  0
5            1                  0                  1                  0                  0
6            1                  1                  0                  0                  0
7            1                  0                  0                  0                  0
8            1                  0                  0                  0                  0
9            1                  0                  0                  0                  0
10           1                  0                  0                  0                  0
11           1                  0                  1                  0                  0
12           1                  1                  0                  0                  0
13           1                  0                  0                  0                  1
14           1                  0                  0                  0                  0
15           1                  1                  0                  0                  0
16           1                  1                  0                  0                  0
17           1                  0                  0                  0                  0
18           1                  0                  0                  0                  0
19           1                  0                  0                  0                  0
20           1                  0                  0                  0                  0
```

But what if I want the interaction for only three of the four levels of the category? I would rather avoid doing this by hand...

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the `dummies` package?

But if not something like this might work:

```
model.matrix(y ~ categorical:dummy, data = Data[ ! Data$categorical %in% 'D', ] )
```

Comment: I'm actually not interested in creating more dummy variables, but in using R's `formula` elements to avoid it. That package certainly looks like it would make creating dummies easier, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Eran here is the rub at rep 48, I cannot comment on the post.  I have updated my answer to provide a potential solution to the OP question.

Comment: @Christopher Your edit simply removes the records from category `D`. I want to keep these records, but not estimate the coefficient on that category.

Comment: @gmacfarlane Am I missing something.  Isn't it trivial since all of the columns will be 0 for those observations save for the intercept.  Isn't it simply a matter of adding back in the Category D rows with 0's everywhere else since the remaining model.matrix will be 0 everywhere else.

Comment: My goal isn't to create a `model.matrix`. It's to tell the `formula` command to do this for me (I have about 15 other variables that I left out of this MWE). This will create a model matrix without the `categoricalD:dummy` column. Which I could do myself, but I was hoping to save several lines of code.